# Excel : Copy and paste multiple rows and columns from one worksheet to another

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

i would like to copy multiple rows from one worksheet to another , i have data starting in one worksheet at A2 row and ends at A108850 and it starts at A2 column and ends at I2 column , how can i copy all that data into another worksheet where row starts with A4 and column starts with A4 and ends with I4.

How could i possibly do it through some macro?.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a code writing service. see [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). beside that I would suggest you try the macro recorder and do exactly what you just described manually, you then have the code to do this :)

Comment: I would never use the macro recorder to create macros due to poor performance. Using correct code will make the macro hundreds or thousands(?) times faster.

Comment: @ErikBlomgren I wouldn't either, but OP didn't provide any code. Thus starting at the macro recorder or trying to code something is the first start, not providing OP with the anwser

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:I108850").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A4")
```

Change the range reference and worksheet's name accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Copy&Paste is an "expensive" operation, the greater the range the more expensive the operation

Should you be interested in values only, you could try this:

```
    Worksheets("DestinationSheetName").Range("A2:I108850").Value = Worksheets("SourceSheetName").Range("A2:I108850").Value
```

**edited** after OP's comment

Should the code in your last comment have the same aim of pasting values only, then change the second statement into the following:

```
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:I108850") '<--| reference the "source" range you want to paste values from
         .Range("A4").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value '<--| resize "destination" range accordingly to "source" one and paste values into it
    End With
```

of course you must check for sheet names to be valid ones for the currently *active* workbook

Comment: Should i create a macro or try the script in microsoft VB Module?

Comment: That piece of code is to be placed within a "Subroutine" that you can write in a VBA module and which you would eventually call by either associating it to a sheet button or by pressing Alt-F8 and choosing your subroutine name from the listbox

Comment: I have done that , but its giving me an syntax error  : 
Sub Copy()

    Worksheets("Performance MMT").Range("A2:I108850").Value = Worksheets("Moscow").Range("A2:I108850").ValueWorksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:I108850").Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4")

End Sub